# .htaccess equivalent in KTOR

Tags: ktor

To allow video to be played in element from my website, but not allowing it through direct link, I created .htaccess in a sub-directory with the source videos, and nothing else. with the below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(mp4|mp3|avi)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://sample.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

I need to do the same with [ktor](http://ktor.io/) server, but do not know how?

Any help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to add an `interceptor` to application and apply these rules directly:

```
intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Infrastructure) {
    // If call matches conditions
    if (call.request.path().endsWith(".mp4") && call.request.headers["Referrer"] != "http://sample.com/video.html") {
        // respond with 400 Bad Request
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        // and stop processing further
        finish()
    }
}
```